# Custom Adapter of ListView

Tags: android, multithreading, android-listview, android-imageview

My  `ListView` have multiple items. Each Item have a `TextView` and two `ImageView`. I have implemented this by using custom adapter. Each `ImageView` in my `ListView` have 5 images. How can i show 5 images repeatedly in a `ImageView` in custom adapter?  I want to repeat the images in all `ImageView` in the interval of 15 seconds.

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public Activity adapterActivity;
    LayoutInflater adapterInflater;
    ImageLoader compImageLoader;
    List<Categary> list;

    ArrayList<String> category = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> leftImage = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> rightImage = new ArrayList<String>();

    public CategoryAdapter(Activity activity, List<Categary> listData) {
        list = listData;
        adapterActivity = activity;
        adapterInflater = (LayoutInflater) adapterActivity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        compImageLoader = new ImageLoader(
                adapterActivity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView lPic, rPic;
        public TextView category;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (vi == null) {

            vi = adapterInflater.inflate(R.layout.categoryadapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.lPic = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.rPic = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            holder.category = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_category);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }
        final Categary assingValue = list.get(position);
        holder.lPic.setTag(assingValue.leftPicture);
        holder.rPic.setTag(assingValue.rightPicture);
        holder.category.setText(assingValue.id);
        compImageLoader.DisplayImage(assingValue.leftPicture, holder.lPic);
        compImageLoader.DisplayImage(assingValue.rightPicture, holder.rPic);
        return vi;
    }          
}
```

Comment: you can use an animationdrawable for that.

Comment: how can i achieve animationdrawable in custom adapter? Is it possible? can you please explain me sir?

Comment: see my answer. If you need more details as to how to put the images in the animation, post some code showing how your images are used in your adapter

Comment: I added above my whole adapter sir. just Take a look.

Comment: it is not very clear what Categary is, what left and rightPicture are inside a Categary (urls, I assume? where are the others?), and what ImageLoader, I assume that is universalImageLoader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) is the right component for that:

In your `getView()`, I assume you have an `ImageView` named `imageView`. I also assume you have an array of Drawables representing your images:

```
AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
for (Drawable image : images) {
    animation.addFrame(image, 15 * 1000L);
}
imageView.setImageDrawable(animation);
animation.start();
```

This can change depending on how your images are available in your application.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have used your code depends on my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn thread in `getView` function for each `ListView` item and put delay of 15 sec in between images.

like this:

```
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                iv.setImageResource(iconID);
                Thread.sleep(15000);
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say that you have the ids of your images in an array.

```
int i=0;
new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        imgView.setImageResource(arrayIds[i]);
    i++;
        if(i==arrayIds.length)
            i=0;
        start();//restart the count down timer for another 15 seconds again
    }
}.start();
```